# How to merge markers in Plotly for my Scattergeo map

Tags: python, plotly

I've gathered a large dataset of longitude and latitude values, and I want to showcase them on a map. After some searching, I came across Plotly. Currently, I am able to generate a map that has all the locations marked on it; however, a lot of markers overlap. This happens because a lot of the locations are situated in large cities such as New York, LA, Washington, etc. Here's an example of my map:

https://i.ibb.co/kcJqZ44/test.png

**What I want** to happen is that Plotly merges markers that are close to each other, and give these combined locations a different colored marker. Here's an example of what I'd like to create:

https://www.scrapehero.com/store/wp-content/uploads/maps/McDonalds_USA.png

**Here's my code:**

```
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scattergeo(
    lon=df['Longitude'],
    lat=df['Latitude'],
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        color="Blue",
        size=3
    )
))

fig.update_layout(
    title = 'This is dope!',
    geo_scope= 'usa',
)

fig.write_image("images/test.png", scale=1, width=1500, height=1080)
```

EDIT: Here's a sample of 10 rows of my dataset (minus a bunch of columns that shouldn't affect what I want to create)

id,City,State,Longitude,Latitude
6174,Bogota,NJ,-74.032736,40.870692
6374,Albuquerque,NM,-106.588451,35.131963
7803,Mcallen,TX,-98.215059,26.185339
49,Boaz,AL,-86.149957,34.199872
4186,Omaha,NE,-96.023101,41.262733
6888,Raleigh,NC,-78.69487,35.767785
6690,Carthage,NC,-79.403632,35.340411
1638,Worcester,MA,-71.778189,42.293615
3000,Meridian,ID,-116.432998,43.619837
36,Tuscaloosa,AL,-87.478128,33.196976

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please add some data to reproduce your problem and being able to help you.

Comment: I have checked the sample data for your desired output and there are no special columns leading to grouping. So I think you need to decide whether the aggregation unit should be a city or a county, calculate the number of stores, get the latitude and longitude of the center of the city or county, and draw it.

Comment: @Hamzah I've added 10 rows of my data as of now.

Comment: @r-beginners , totally agree with you.

Comment: @r-beginners how about grouping based on distance? Please see my answer below.

Comment: @amance Grouping by distance is one good approach.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, Plotly can't do this automatically. You'd have to alter your dataframe and decide which points are close enough together to be grouped. For this dataframe, since the points are rather far away from each other, I've defined "close" to be within 200 miles.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''id,City,State,Longitude,Latitude
    6174,Bogota,NJ,-74.032736,40.870692
    6374,Albuquerque,NM,-106.588451,35.131963
    7803,Mcallen,TX,-98.215059,26.185339
    49,Boaz,AL,-86.149957,34.199872
    4186,Omaha,NE,-96.023101,41.262733
    6888,Raleigh,NC,-78.69487,35.767785
    6690,Carthage,NC,-79.403632,35.340411
    1638,Worcester,MA,-71.778189,42.293615
    3000,Meridian,ID,-116.432998,43.619837
    36,Tuscaloosa,AL,-87.478128,33.196976'''))
```

Original Figure

[image: Original Figure]

```
def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = np.radians([lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1

    haver_formula = np.sin(dlat/2)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dlon/2)**2

    r = 3958.756 #6371 for distance in KM for miles use 3958.756
    dist = 2 * r * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(haver_formula))
    return pd.Series(dist)

#self join table
df2 = pd.merge(df[['id', 'Longitude', 'Latitude']].assign(key=1),df[['id', 'Longitude', 'Latitude']].assign(key=1), on='key').drop('key', axis=1)

#drop duplicates
df2 = df2[df2['id_x']!=df2['id_y']].reset_index(drop=True)

#find distances
df2['dist'] = haversine(df2['Longitude_x'], df2['Latitude_x'], df2['Longitude_y'], df2['Latitude_y'])

#for now we'll define "close" as being within 200 miles
df_close = df2[df2['dist']<=200]
close_ids = df_close['id_x'].drop_duplicates().tolist()

#start of final dataframe
df_new = df[~df['id'].isin(close_ids)]

#find mid-point for points "close" together
while len(close_ids)>0:
    for i in close_ids:
        recip_ids = df_close['id_y'][df_close['id_x']==i].tolist()
        df_new = pd.concat([df_new, df[['Longitude','Latitude']][df['id'].isin([i]+recip_ids)].mean().reset_index().set_index('index').transpose().assign(id='_'.join([str(x) for x in [i]+recip_ids]))])
        for x in [i]+recip_ids:
            close_ids.remove(x)

#final df
df_new
          id         City State   Longitude   Latitude color
1       6374  Albuquerque    NM -106.588451  35.131963   NaN
2       7803      Mcallen    TX  -98.215059  26.185339   NaN
4       4186        Omaha    NE  -96.023101  41.262733   NaN
8       3000     Meridian    ID -116.432998  43.619837   NaN
0  6174_1638          NaN   NaN  -72.905462  41.582154   red
0  6888_6690          NaN   NaN  -79.049251  35.554098   red
0      49_36          NaN   NaN  -86.814042  33.698424   red

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scattergeo(
    lon=df_new['Longitude'],
    lat=df_new['Latitude'],
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        color=df_new['color'],
        size=10
    )
))

fig.update_layout(
    title = 'This is dope!',
    geo_scope= 'usa',
)
```

New Figure

[image: Final Figure]

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, it looks like Plotly added this in v5.11. [Here](https://plotly.com/python/scattermapbox/#add-clusters)'s an example from Plotly using a sample dataset.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

px.set_mapbox_access_token(open(".mapbox_token").read())
df = pd.read_csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_february_us_airport_traffic.csv"
)
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df, lat="lat", lon="long", size="cnt", zoom=3)
fig.update_traces(cluster=dict(enabled=True))
fig.show()
```

[image: Fig]

and zoomed in
[image: fig2]